# Retrive javascript properties from html page using C#

Tags: c#, jquery, windows-phone

I want to know if there is a way to get specific property of javascript function from a webpage using c#,

here is the function I found within the site :

```
(function($){
window.Ibles.pageContext = $.extend(window.Ibles.pageContext, {         
    numStepsByWordCount: 1,
    allSteps: true,
    ibleID: "EPAOKDUH8I455QP",
    ibleUrl: "/id/PVC-longbow/",
    ibleType: "Step by Step",
    ibleCategory: "outside",
    ibleChannel: "survival"
});
})(jQuery);
```

I need to get the ibleID property.

Thx before

Comment: No, but you can manually parse the HTML to extract the value you want

Comment: @KooKiz thank you for your idea. for now what i do is just find the string and use its index for substring. but I dont think its the best way to do it.

Comment: Regular expressions can be more robust than substring. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the value easily by using a regular expression:

```
var match = Regex.Match(content, "ibleID: \"(?<id>\\w+)\"");

if (match.Success)
{
    var id = match.Groups["id"].Value;
}
else 
{
    // id not found
}
```

Comment: awesome this is exactly what i need, thx a lot @KooKiz
cheers